# Create//append JSON array from text file in linux with loop

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

I have a below file in txt format. I want to arrange the data in json array format in linux and append more such data with for/while loop in the same json array based on condition. Please help me with the best way to achieve this.

```
File
Name:Rock
Name:Clock
```

```
{“Array" :[
{
"Name": "Rock",
},
{
"Name”: "Clock”,
}
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I was uploading the data with curl command in json format but I am not able to achieve the required format. Now I am thinking to first create the data locally and then POST. This is the way I was posting data in json format. $(curl -o /dev/null -s  -X POST “${url}" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: ${base}” -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d “{\”data1\”:\”${data1}\”,\”data2\”:\”${data2}\”}”).      But this way I am not able to append the data in the new array and unable to append using curl.

Comment: Your expected output is not JSON format.

Comment: Take a look at [convert text file with line breaks to json with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60425030/convert-text-file-with-line-breaks-to-json-with-jq). Your question as-stated is simpler than the ask there, but that means that the answer you need is simpler, and can be constructed by taking the answers there and trimming out the parts you don't need.

Comment: BTW, is `File` *really* part of the input file?

Comment: And does your intended output file *really* have "smart quotes" instead of normal ASCII quotes? (Keep in mind that only the latter are permissible as JSON syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your initial file is object.json and that it contains an empty object, {};
and that at the beginning of each iteration, the key:value pairs  are defined in another file, kv.txt.

Then at each iteration, you can update array.json using the invocation:

```
< kv.txt jq -Rn --argfile object object.json -f program.jq | sponge object.json
```

where program.jq contains the jq program:

```
$object | .Array += 
  reduce inputs as $in ([]; . + [$in | capture("(?<k>^[^:]*): *(?<v>.*)") | {(.k):.v} ])
```

(`sponge` is part of the moreutils package.  If it cannot be used, then you will have to use another method of updating object.json.)